# Failed to load module [redis], error: /usr/local/lsws//modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: zend_objects_destroy_object

Tags: php, redis, phpredis, litespeed

I am trying to use open LiteSpeed to host my php application + Redis. I compiled Redis to its respective `redis.so` but it fails to load the extension.
Here is the list of steps that i tried to compile this extension

```
1) wget https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/develop.zip
2) mv develop develop.zip 
3) unzip develop.zip 
4) mv develop.zip redis
5) cd redis
6) /usr/local/lsws/lsphp5/bin/phpize
7) ./configure --enable-redis --with-php-config=/usr/local/lsws/lsphp5/bin/php-config
8) make 
9) make install
```

I get redis.so but on restarting the server the plugin fails to load and i get the following error:
 `Failed to load module [redis], error: /usr/local/lsws//modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: zend_objects_destroy_object`

Answer (score 0):

I was using a wrong version of php-redis.